# Reverse lookup in Ruby (preferably with Dnsruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using Dnsruby, which is great, but how do I do a reverse lookup for the hostname associated with an IP address? Or if not dnsruby, other suggested routes?

Here is what I am working with so far, and I figured that my query would have the resolved name also, but its not apparent to me.

```
resolver = Resolver.new
query = resolver.query("example.com")
ip =  query.answer.first.address.to_s
```

As for more background, I am basically using this in a monitoring app, and with apps on Amazon EC2, and I'd like to see what the IP we've been assigned resolves to. I am hoping I can then use that to further assess potential its location etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Socket class`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/socket/rdoc/Socket.html) can be used for looking up host name based on address.

See [this answer](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/171218#750910) for an example.